# Reuse existing types not working for silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, web-services

I have two web services that return the same type.

It doesn't work... it generated proxies for each and sees them as two different types.

What are the typical causes for this?

Do I need to be using WCF for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add service references manually it treats them as completely independent and does not match the types.

If you use a manual WSDL generator (the command line tool) you have the option to merge types.

*(I did this years ago so I don't remember the specific options, but hope this helps point you in the right direction. Maybe someone else can provide a recent link?)*